# How does qobject_cast work?

Tags: c++, qt, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I just found the following code in Qt and I'm a bit confused what's happening here.

Especially as to what `reinterpret_cast<T>(0)` does?

```
template <class T>
inline T qobject_cast(const QObject *object)
{
    // this will cause a compilation error if T is not const
    register T ptr = static_cast<T>(object);
    Q_UNUSED(ptr);

#if !defined(QT_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES) && !defined(QT_NO_QOBJECT_CHECK)
    reinterpret_cast<T>(0)->qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro(*reinterpret_cast<T>(const_cast<QObject *>(object)));
#endif
    return static_cast<T>(const_cast<QObject *>(reinterpret_cast<T>(0)->staticMetaObject.cast(const_cast<QObject *>(object))));
}
```

Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a little complicated...

Remember that [`qobject_cast<T>(obj)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) is a way to dynamically cast a `QObject` to the target type `T` which also derives from `QObject`. Now, for this to work, the macro `Q_OBJECT` should be included in the definition of class `T`.

Apparently, the `qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro` call is for checking that the class really contains the Q_OBJECT macro. When the macro is expanded, it contains the following definitions:

```
template <typename T> inline void qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro(const T &_q_argument) const 
   { int i = qYouForgotTheQ_OBJECT_Macro(this, &_q_argument); i = i; }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline int qYouForgotTheQ_OBJECT_Macro(T, T) { return 0; }
```

So if you have an object `x` of type `T` and an object `y` of type `U`, the call `x->qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro(y)` calls the function `qYouForgotTheQ_OBJECT_Macro` with parameters of types `T*` and `U*`. Because the function is templated with a single type parameter, the types `T` and `U` must be the same.

Now, if you call `x->qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro(x)` then you should expect the types to be the same and for the compilation to trivially succeed. However, remember that `this` has the same type as the class the method was defined in. So if `x` is of a class that was derived from T but doesn't contain its own definition of `qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro`, the call will fail.

So we have a way to check if the target type T contains the correct mechanism for the dynamic cast, but we don't have a object of type T to call this method on yet. That's what the `reinterpret_cast<T>(0)` is for. We don't need an actual object as `this`, since the compiler only needs the object types for the check to succeed. Instead, we call a method on a null pointer of type T.

I don't think this is allowed by the C++ standard, but it works since `this` isn't actually used inside the method.

Comment: Could you clarify which part you don't think is allowed by the C++ standard?  I'm curious.

Comment: The method is static, it's not called "on" the pointer.  `this` would reference the caller and not a non-existent object.

Comment: `Now, for this to work, the macro Q_OBJECT should be included in the definition of class T.` This might be wrong. Qt document [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/metaobjects.html) says `While it is possible to use QObject as a base class without the Q_OBJECT macro and without meta-object code, neither signals and slots nor the other features described here will be available if the Q_OBJECT macro is not used. `